# Rails db:seed doesn't create records when foreign key is a large number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to populate a mysql2 database and not all records are being added into the database.

This is my schema

```
create_table "accounts", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name_es"
  t.string "name_en"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "dbid"  

create_table "company_account_categories", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "company_type"
  t.integer "account_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_company_account_categories_on_account_id"

add_foreign_key "company_account_categories", "accounts"
```

In my seeds I have CompanyAccountCategory records with account_id between 101 and 177 which all get wrote into the DB, while records with account_id 22077 or greater are not.

Example:

```
CompanyAccountCategory.find_or_create_by(account_id: 176, company_type: 4)
CompanyAccountCategory.find_or_create_by(account_id: 22133, company_type: 1)
```

Comment: Does `Account.find(22133)` exist? The foreign key constraint will prevent you from adding relationships to records that don't exist.

Comment: @ScottBartell it does exist

Comment: If you do a `CompanyAccountCategory.find_or_create_by!(account_id: 22133, company_type: 1)` do you get an exception? And what SQL is generated?